# How to dynamic modify super classes of a class using asm or javassist

Tags: java-bytecode-asm, javassist

How to dynamic modify a class's super classes to point to another class as its superclass by `asm` or `javassist`?

I know how to modify a class's methods and fields.

Comment: What do you mean by “modify a class's super classes”? Do you want to truly modify the superclass or just the class’ declaration to point to another class as its superclass?

Comment: I'm sorry to cause confusion to you, i just want to modify the class's declaration to point to another class as its superclass

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `setSuperclass`. Here is a small example:

```
CtClass c = pool.getCtClass("com.my.class.A"); 
c.setSuperclass(pool.getCtClass("com.my.class.B"));
```

[Here](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#setSuperclass-javassist.CtClass-) is the documentation for this method:

> **public void setSuperclass​(CtClass clazz)**
> **throws CannotCompileException**
>
> Changes a super class unless this object represents an interface. The new super class must
> be compatible with the old one; for example, it should inherit from
> the old super class.
>
> If this object represents an interface, this
> method is equivalent to addInterface(); it appends clazz to the list
> of the super interfaces extended by that interface. Note that an
> interface can extend multiple super interfaces.